# How to upload image convert it to byte array and store it as the image property of a class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, image-uploading, storing-data

In my Create View, for creating new vehicles. I want to have an File Upload will take the uploaded file convert it to a byte array and then store it as the model.image.

I already have an image attribute stored as a byte array in my vehicle class. I can seed this using File.ReadAllBytes and the image displays fine.

However I am having difficulty using an image upload to store it as the models image attribute.

Here is how I'm converting the byte array to an image

This is the View

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="@Url.Action("RenderImage", new { id = item.VehicleID})"
```

This is the Controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> RenderImage(int id)
        {
            Vehicle v = await db.Vehicles.FindAsync(id);

            byte[] carImage = v.Image;

            return File(carImage, "image/jpg");
        }
```

In the Create View for Vehicle, how can I have file upload set the Vehicle.Image as the bytes from the uploaded file?

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working?  A Google search for something like "asp.net mvc file upload" would definitely get you started.  Are you using the `HttpPostedFileBase` class?  Is the file successfully uploading?  What specifically doesn't work?

Comment: You want to create a bitmap from image.